# How to make a player move with the arrows using Phaser 3 and socket.io?

Tags: socket.io, phaser-framework

How to make a player move with the arrows using Phaser 3 and socket.io on the client and on the server?

I want the player to move up and down when pressing the upper and lower keys, and left and right when pressing the left and right keys. any examples?

Comment: how does your code look like? what exactly is the Problem?

Comment: no problem, I just want to know how to implement it.